# Shorthand form when using += on type string | null?

Tags: typescript

What is the best way to write the following Javascript in Typescript?

```js
let a, b; /* @type {string | null} */
a += b;
```

The obvious option is

```
let a: string | null, b: string | null;
a = a || '' + b || '';
```

But this loses some of the conciseness of the original expression. Is there any other way to write this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter in this scenario, but consider using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) instead of `||`. It only returns the right-hand side value when the left-hand side is `null` or `undefined`, instead of any falsy value such as `''`.

You could do this in 2 ways:

```
// Your original method
// Note that + has a higher precedence than ?? and ||, so you need the parentheses
a = (a ?? '') + (b ?? '')

// Give a a default value first
a ??= ''
// Then add b or '' if b is null to a
a += b ?? ''
```

The `??=` is part of TypeScript's [short-circuiting assignment operators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#short-circuiting-assignment-operators) and `a ??= ''` is the same as `a = a ?? ''`.

However, neither of these are as concise as `a += b`.

Comment: We can further shorten this by writing `a ??= (b ?? '')`. Didn't know about the ?? operator, thanks!

Comment: @AkshathSivaprasad If `a` and `b` are both non-`null`, your code will do the wrong thing - the value of `a` will be lost.